# Trying to replace Controls.Clear() to avoid memory leak doesn’t work – why?

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks

I replaced:

```
panel.Controls.Clear();
```

with:

```
Clear(panel);
```

Where:

```
public static void Clear(Control ctrl)
{
    while (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0) ctrl.Controls[0].Dispose();
}
```

And I get the following error: at `Application.Run(new Form1());`
System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Label'.

Any idea why that might be?

Thanks.

EDIT:
See [How to Clear() controls without causing a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705234/how-to-clear-controls-without-causing-a-memory-leak)

EDIT: Sorry, I’m probably disposing of something which I just want to remove from its parent. I’ll check that. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Why do you think that such a method would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was probably disposing of some `Control`s I *was* using later on in the code.

Answer (score 4):

`Dispose()` has **nothing** to do with memory under normal circumstances. It doesn't release memory, it doesn't remove the object from a collection, and it doesn't invoke the garbage collector. Instead, the purpose of `.Dispose()` is to clean up *non-memory* resources: database connections, sockets, device handles, gdi handles, etc.

The only way this could possible help you fix a memory issue is if you're using custom controls that each rely on code in an unmanaged (non-.Net) dll.

Comment: It also releases gdi+ handles on normal controls. That's why you need to call `Dispose` on controls.

Comment: It's a terminology problem, then. You might leak _handles_, but you won't leak memory.

Comment: All Dispose does is release the handles _now_. The handles would eventually be released during finalization that would take place as part of garbage collection.

Comment: Nope, the removed controls are parented to the parking window.  That's a permanent and unrecoverable leak.  Both the handle *and* the memory for the control object.  Rules are different for the Control class.

Answer (score 0):

You need remove controls you disposed, but there might be a better approach:

```
public static void Clear(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach(Control c in ctrl.Controls) c.Dispose();
    ctrl.Controls.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Very Bad Idea.  This only disposes every other control.  Try it, drop 4 buttons on a form and single step through the foreach loop to see how often Dispose() is called.

Comment: @HansPassant Out of interest, _why_ does it only dispose every other control?